# Remove whitespace when highlighting security code in HTML emails

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm creating an invitational email template for the new users of my platform. Within the email, they get their login details such as:

**Username: JoeBloggs@twitter.com**

**Security Code: w9J6,Fcd@**

Although when they highlight their username or security code they get 1-2 whitespace at the end.

I tried putting the outputs into a **SPAN** or **PRE** but can't seem to remove the whitespaces. The **PRE** tag fixes the issue when I use it within my browser but doesn't work within the email. **I am unable to use any javascript** as this will be blocked by the email providers.

**Extra info** -

This is being sent by AWS cognito so it currently looks like:

```
Your Password:
<pre>{####}</pre>
```

Comment: I don't know if this would be an option, but there's the possibility of using [`user-select: all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) on the `<pre>` element: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sp49L27x/).

Comment: Have you tried adding a `<br>` directly after the output?

Comment: This gets my vote, as we all get these password reset messages, and it is super-annoying when you cannot double-click and highlight the whole thing at once. Thank you for thinking this problem through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user-select: all` has fixed the issue